# ImageView hidden behind Button out of ideas

Tags: android, button, imageview

I have an ImageView moving across the screen but once it reaches a button it goes behind it and the ImageView becomes hidden. They are on different layouts. I have tried bringing both the ImageView and the Layout to the front, and making the button both invisible and transparent (setAlpha(0)). Not sure what code would help here but just ask and I will happily post whatever needed.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".MainActivity"

android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/friendly1"


    />
<Button

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/choice1"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/btnRow1"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:onClick="onClickRow1"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in the init() method:

```
 friendly1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.friendly1);
 friendly1.bringToFront();

RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
mainLayout.bringToFront();
```

Comment: post the xml of the fragment/activity

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The layout code above doesn't make sense - you have an closing </LinearLayout> without an opening <LinearLayout> ??

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the views from their parent, and the re-add them at specified indices. This will allow you to control which views are located in front of/behind others.

```java
 ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)viewToRemove.getParent();
            parent.removeView(viewToRemove);
            parent.addView(viewToRemove, index);
```

Where 'index' is the int value of the index where you want to place the view. Views with higher indices appear above those with lower ones.

Extra tip: If you want, you can use the same index for all of the views you want to add, the ones you add first will appear below the ones you add next (because the ViewGroup works like an ArrayList).